# Filtro do título, filtrar a TAG

Tags: novo-recurso

**Enquanto criamos o título de uma pergunta**, ela faz pesquisas e trás possíveis perguntas em "*Perguntas que talvez já têm sua resposta*".

Mesmo que coloquemos a **TAG, ele não filtra**, trazendo diversas perguntas de outras TAGs, sendo que, poderia filtrar os assuntos específicos da TAG.

[image: tag]

Comment: Não vejo necessidade de um recurso desse, até porque há pouco tempo já estavam testando uma forma de wizard para usuarios novos ao criarem perguntas. Veteranos já poderiam ter noção de uso da barra de pesquisa, por mais limitada que ela seja, mas o resultado dela e dessa pesquisa citada na pergunta é a mesma.

Comment: Mas está trazendo sugestões praticamente incorretas, concorda? Estou pesquisando sobre PHP, e está me trazendo sobre ORACLE, JS, etc. Se já tem o negócio aí, porque não melhorar? Só se realmente será abrangida por outra atualização.

Comment: Acredito que seja o mesmo mecanismo de pesquisa, q já não funciona muito bem, se eles não melhoraram o mecanismo de pesquisa até hoje, duvido muito que melhorem agora.

Comment: Tive uma ideia aqui, adicione a tag antes de criar o titulo, e veja se ele ao menos leva em consideração as tags ja adicionadas. Nunca testei isso, mas vai que funciona.

Comment: Nada. Tag PHP, título: "array_filter com mais " , resultados: "Excel com mais de 300 mil linhas" :`D

Comment: realmente a busca é bem imprecisa